# ClientContext query by Title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, csom

I want to do something like the below. But I'm not sure how exactly to do it. I just want to return items with similar Title to be efficient.

```
List pages = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Web Part Gallery");

ListItemCollection existingWebParts = pages.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

clientContext.Load(existingWebParts, items => items.Include(item => item["Title"]).Where(obj => obj == "CollapsibleAccordion.webpart"));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is showing as syntax error.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an object with a string inside the lambda expression. I mean following part is causing the syntax error

```
.Where(obj => obj == "CollapsibleAccordion.webpart")
```

You should `"CollapsibleAccordion.webpart"` with a column like `Title` or etc.

```
clientContext.Load(existingWebParts, items => items.Include(item => item["Title"]).Where(obj => obj["Title"] == "CollapsibleAccordion.webpart"));
```

Comment: Thanks Atish. Unfortunately, it gives me this error: Additional information: The expression (obj.get_Item("Title") == "CollapsibleAccordion.webpart") is not supported.

Instead, I used CamlQuery to get only the webpart I need.

Thanks